# How to make my code output comma after all values that go under criteria besides the last

Tags: c#, .net, string

Code needs to output comma after values that go under criteria, besides the *last one*, can't seem to find a way how to make code ignore the *last comma*.

```
public class LabWork1
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("n: ");
        int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        var numbers = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        { 
            if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
            {
                numbers.Append(i);
                numbers.Append(", ");
            }
        }

        Console.Write(numbers.ToString());
    }
}
```

Should be

```
3, 5, 6, 9
```

Actual (note the *last comma*)

```
3, 5, 6, 9,
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8) and LINQ instead:

```
var numbers = string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(1 , n)
                                .Where(i => i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0));
Console.Write(numbers);
```

Just make sure that you have already added the following to your `using` directive:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 1):

To repair your *current solution*, add comma `,` *before* adding `i`:
when having empty `numbers` add `i`; if `numbers` is not empty, add `", "` first and then `i`.

```
    ...
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    { 
            if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
            {
                    // Add comma (if required) first...
                    if (numbers.Length > 0)
                            numbers.Append(", ");        

                    // ...and only then value
                    numbers.Append(i);
            }
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use others solutions to ignore extra comma from string builder.

But if you want to remove `,` from existing code, you can trim comma and space.

You can use `TrimEnd(',', ' ')` to trim last comma and space from output string

```
Console.Write(numbers.ToString().TrimEnd(',', ' '));
```

MSDN: [.TrimEnd()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trimend?view=netframework-4.8)

---

Second approach:

Instead of appending `i` in string builder, store it in `List<int>`.
While writing `numbers` to console use `string.Join()`.

MSDN : `string.Join(string separator, IEnumerable<T> values)`

> Concatenates the members of a constructed IEnumerable collection of
>   type String, using the specified separator between each member

Your solution will look like

```
...
//Store all i's in list
List<int> numbers = new List<int>(); 
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{ 
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0)
        numbers.Add(i);
}

Console.Write(string.Join(", ", numbers));
...
```